# How to Set Security Headers in Nginx Conf

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I added the following header in Nginx conf

`add_header X-Frame-Options “SAMEORIGIN”` and then it's working fine.

[image]

Then I added another header like this

```
add_header X-Frame-Options “SAMEORIGIN”
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

But the `X-XSS-Protection` is not getting reflected in the Response Headers, only `X-Frame-Options` is getting added.
Then I removed the `X-Frame-Options` from the Nginx conf file, then also it is showing the `X-Frame-Options` in the Response Headers but not the other one.
I am not sure if Nginx cached the previous conf file or it is happening due to some other configurations.

Comment: Are you adding these all in the same place?  One common issue is that if you use `add_header` in one level like `server` and then put in another `add_header` in a lower level like `location`, **all the server level `add-header`s will be ignored**.  I don't know if this is your case, but it's the first thing I would check.  Here is a good article on this https://www.peterbe.com/plog/be-very-careful-with-your-add_header-in-nginx

Comment: ... the same happens with `proxy_set_header`, though that's not related to your question.

Comment: The `;` is missing from the end of the first `add_header` line.

Comment: @RichardSmith That `;` helped. Thanks